# IndexOutOfRangeException when using Rg.Plugins.Popup in xamarin forms android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation, popup

I am using Rg.plugins.popup nuget package version 2.0.0.10. I am getting PopupNavigationImpl.PopAllAsync (System.Boolean animate) System.IndexOutOfRangeException: No Page in PopupStack crash in appcenter. In code i am using await PopupNavigation.PopAllAsync(); this line getting crashed. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You could post the issue to https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues

Comment: Can you downgrade the nuget to lower version and try?